# IEnumerable<CustomType> in PowerShell

Tags: .net, generics, powershell, ienumerable

I'm trying to use `Enumerable.ToList()` in PowerShell. Apparently, to do that, I have to explicitly convert the object to `IEnumerable<CustomType>`, but I am unable to do that. It seems I can't correctly write `IEnumerable<CustomType>` in PowerShell. Both `IEnumerable<string>` and `CustomType` itself work correctly (the custom type I'm trying to use is called `WpApiLib.Page`), so I don't know what can I be doing wrong.

```
PS C:\Users\Svick> [Collections.Generic.IEnumerable``1[System.String]]

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    IEnumerable`1


PS C:\Users\Svick> [WpApiLib.Page]

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Page                                     System.Object


PS C:\Users\Svick> [Collections.Generic.IEnumerable``1[WpApiLib.Page]]
Unable to find type [Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WpApiLib.Page]]: make su
re that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
At line:1 char:51
+ [Collections.Generic.IEnumerable``1[WpApiLib.Page]] <<<<
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the answer here: [Powershell Generic Collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184476/powershell-generic-collections).  It looks like this is an unfortunate consequence of how PowerShell interprets generics, and you'll need to fully qualify the `WpApiLib.Page` type.

Answer (score 7):

In PowerShell v2 you can use

```
Collections.Generic.IEnumerable[string]
```

to refer to `IEnumberable<string>`. The syntax works for `New-Object` (though not with an interface) and it seems to be valid for casts, too.