# Can I use System.Core.dll/System.Collections.Generic.HashSet in powershell?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, powershell

I'd like to use a HashSet in a powershell script. I think I've figured out how to instantiate generic collection objects by doing:

```
[type] $strType = "string"
$listClass = [System.Collections.Generic.List``1]
$listObject = $base.MakeGenericType(@($t))
$myList = New-Object $setObject
```

This works fine for lists and dictionaries, but when I try to create a HashSet I get:

```
Unable to find type [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
```

So it looks like now I need to load System.Core.dll but I can't seem to get powershell to load that assembly. For example calling *[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Core")* causes this exception:

```
"LoadWithPartialName" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
```

Any pointers?

Comment: are you in powershell v1 or v2?

Comment: I'm on Win2k8 R2 and get-host says version 2.0

Comment: Possible duplicate: See answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184476/powershell-generic-collections

Answer (score 25, accepted):

PowerShell 2.0 makes this easier by 1) adding the Add-Type cmdlet for loading an assembly and 2) updates to the syntax to make specifying a closed generic type name simpler e.g.:

```
PS> Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Core
PS> $h = new-object 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]'
PS> $h.Add('f')
True
```

Comment: Can I then specify parameter type in functions by doing `[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][hashset]`?

Comment: Yes but you need to specify the parameter type as `[Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]` substitute for string the type you need to store in the hashset.