# Passing in an empty set throws an error

Tags: powershell, set, hashset, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to use a `HashSet` in my powershell script as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3321712/1305516) answer.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Core
$set= new-object 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]'
```

But if I make a function which expects such a set

```
function foo([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]$set){
```

and pass in the set

```
foo($set)
```

I get an error if `$set` is empty:

```
Cannot bind argument to parameter '$set' because it is an empty collection.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [script.ps1], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyCollectionNotAllowed,script.ps1
```

But if I add something to `$set` beforehand I dont get an issue.

Why cant the parameter bind to an empty set, and how can I get it to bind to such a set?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can mark the function as allowing the empty HashTable using the `AllowEmptyCollection` attribute:

```
function foo([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][AllowEmptyCollection()][Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]$set)
```

Comment: PowerShell does not like mandatory parameters to be empty and enforces this by default.  But, if you want to allow it, you can use AllowNull, AllowEmptyString, AllowEmptyCollection, depending on your situation.

Comment: Interesting. Do you have a link as to why this is?

Comment: It is documented in `Get-Help about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters` (on technet @ https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx)

Comment: @DavidGrinberg It's quite simple, allowing you to pass "nothing" kinda defeats the purpose of the Mandatory attribute

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thats silly. In C# there are no issues with passing in empty collections.