# Declaring a generic list of a third party assembly type in Powershell 2

Tags: .net, powershell

I am trying to create a new `Collections.Generic.List` object of type `Amazon.Cloudwatch.Model.Dimensions` in Powershell 2.0.

I can create an `Amazon.Cloudwatch.Model.Dimensions` object successfully with:

```
> $dimension = New-Object Amazon.Cloudwatch.Model.Dimensions
```

And I can create a `Collections.Generic.List` object of type `string` with:

```
> $list = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[string]
```

However, when I try and create a `Collections.Generic.List` object of type `Amazon.Cloudwatch.Model.Dimensions`, I get the following error:

```
> $list = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[Amazon.Cloudwatch.Model.Dimension]

New-Object : Cannot find type 
[Collections.Generic.List[Amazon.Cloudwatch.Model.Dimension]]: make sure the assembly containing this type is loaded.
At line:1 char:19
+ $list = New-Object <<<<  
Collections.Generic.List[Amazon.Cloudwatch.Model.Dimension]
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], 
PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

The same statement works on Powershell 3.0, so it would appear this is being caused by the way Powershell 2.0 generics look up assemblies. According to [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11975130/generic-type-of-generic-type-in-powershell) there is a bug in Powershell 2.0 that might be related:

> However, there's an unfortunate catch. In PowerShell 2.0, there's a bug when you mix and match BCL and 3rd party types as type parameters. The latter need to be assembly qualified:

```
# broken over two lines for clarity with backtick escape
$o = new-object ('collections.generic.dictionary[[{0}],[{1}]]' -f `
    [type1].fullname, [type2].fullname)
```

> Hope this helps. In PowerShell 3.0, this has been fixed.

I have (sort of) attempted this without success.

And [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184476/powershell-generic-collections) suggests qualifying the assembly even more with:

> The solution is to specify the fully qualified assembly name for the generic parameter types. It's extremely ugly, but works:

```
$bar = new-object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary``2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]"
```

I have tried:

```
> $list = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.List``1[[Amazon.CloudWatch.Model.Dimension, AWSSDK.CloudWatch, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=885c28607f98e604]]"
```

Also without success.

```
> $list = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.List``1[[Amazon.CloudWatch.Model.Dimension, AWSSDK.CloudWatch, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=885c28607f98e604]]"
New-Object : Cannot find type 
[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Amazon.CloudWatch.Model.Dimension, AWSSDK.CloudWatch, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=885c28607f98e604]]]: make sure the assembly containing this type is loaded.
At line:1 char:22
+ $dimlist = New-Object <<<<  
"System.Collections.Generic.List``1[[Amazon.CloudWatch.Model.Dimension, AWSSDK.CloudWatch, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=885c28607f98e604]]"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Note: `Amazon.Cloudwatch.Model.Dimensions` comes from [The AWS SDK for .NET](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is tested working in powershell version 2.0, having used a combination of ideas from the posts you linked to in your question:

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS SDK for .NET\bin\Net35\AWSSDK.CloudWatch.dll"
$o = "System.Collections.Generic.List``1" -as "Type"
$o = $o.MakeGenericType("Amazon.Cloudwatch.Model.Dimension" -as "Type")
$list = [Activator]::CreateInstance($o)

$list.gettype() | select UnderlyingSystemType

UnderlyingSystemType
--------------------
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Amazon.CloudWatch.Model.Dimension]
```

Comment: I have tested this with a naked Windows 7 VM and can confirm it works with a PSH v.2.0 with CLR Version 2.0.50727.8669.
I had also installed .net fx 4.0 (I guess this is not needed) and the AWS SDK, latest version.

Comment: Nailed it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to test this end-to-end. Certainly I can confirm the issue.

I was thinking, though, why not try to be more generic when declaring the list type and seeing if that flies.

```
#Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS SDK for .NET\bin\Net35\AWSSDK.CloudWatch.dll"
$list = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
$d = $dims = New-Object Amazon.Cloudwatch.Model.Dimension
$d.name = "AutoScalingGroup"
$d.value = "xy"
$list.Add($dim)
$list | Get-Member
```

Here is a screenshot. Thoughts?

[image]

Comment: I can confirm this also works, though I don't know if it really flies since additional painful casts could be necessary.

Comment: Thanks Sam, upvoted your answer but agree with the above comment.