# Assembly doesn't load the first time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-cloudwatch

I have this line in my code

```
$dimension = New-Object Amazon.CloudWatch.Model.Dimension
```

When I run the code the first time, it gives me this error

```
New-Object : Cannot find type [Amazon.CloudWatch.Model.Dimension]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
```

But when I run it again, with no changes whatsoever, it runs perfectly fine.

What's going on?

Cheers

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46116352/9898643) help?

Comment: As to why it runs the second time without errors, that is because `$dimension = New-Object Amazon.CloudWatch.Model.Dimension` implicitely loads the needed assembly, but that is too late to have it available in the first run.

Comment: Thanks. I solved it by importing the module at runtime and that loaded the assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I solved it by importing the module at runtime and that loaded the assembly.