# Powershell - Missing System.Collections.Generic in C:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use this code in Powershell:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Collections.Generic"
```

However I get this error:

```
Add-Type : Cannot add type. One or more required assemblies are missing.
```

I've looked in C:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL and can see that there is no folder named System.Collections.Generic.

Do I need to download this library, if so where?

Comment: @Keith Hill gives you the answer a few minutes ago !

Answer (score 1):

There is no `System.Collections.Generic` assembly. That is a namespace. A large portion of the types in that namespace are in the core library assembly, `mscorlib.dll` which is already available in Powershell since Powershell is .Net.

Go to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Collections.Generic(v=vs.110).aspx) for the namespace, find the type you are trying to use, and you can see the assembly it is in, and remember that there is not necessarily a one to one relationship between assemblies and namespaces.

Using generic types is a bit involved in Powershell and can depend on using reflection, or formatting complex type names.

See [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184476/powershell-generic-collections) for some more details.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind,
not sure why that doesn't work, but turns out I don't need it anyway.

I had this code which for some reason wasn't working intially because it couldn't find [Collections.Generic.List[String]], but now it seems to work:

```
[string[]] $csvUserInfo = @([IO.File]::ReadAllLines($script:EmailListCsvFile))
[Collections.Generic.List[String]]$x = $csvUserInfo
```

Answer (score 0):

I would answer by another question, Why do you need this assembly ?

Can you try to replace your code by :

```
$x = [IO.File]::ReadAllLines($script:EmailListCsvFile)
```

In PowerShell it should work.