# In PowerShell 5 is it possible to declare generic properties for a class?

Tags: class, powershell, generics, powershell-5.0

[PowerShell version 5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/wmf/5.0/class_newtype) introduced the `Class` keyword, making it easier to create custom classes in PowerShell. The announcement only provides [a brief summary on properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/wmf/5.0/class_newtype#properties):

> All properties are public. Properties require either a newline or semicolon. If no object type is specified, the property type is object.

So far so good. Which means that I can create a class that looks like this with ease:

```
Class Node
{
    [String]$Label
    $Nodes
}
```

Where I run into problems is that by not specifying a type for `$Nodes` it defaults to `System.Object`. My goal is to use a `System.Collections.Generic.List` type, but thus far have not figured out how to do so.

```
Class Node
{
    [String]$Label
    [System.Collections.Generic.List<Node>]$Nodes
}
```

The above results in a whole litany of issues:

```
At D:\Scripts\Test.ps1:4 char:36
+     [System.Collections.Generic.List<Node>]$Nodes
+                                    ~
Missing ] at end of attribute or type literal.
At D:\Scripts\Test.ps1:4 char:37
+     [System.Collections.Generic.List<Node>]$Nodes
+                                     ~
Missing a property name or method definition.
At D:\Scripts\Test.ps1:4 char:5
+     [System.Collections.Generic.List<Node>]$Nodes
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
At D:\Scripts\Test.ps1:5 char:1
+ }
+ ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EndSquareBracketExpectedAtEndOfAttribute
```

Which leads me to my question how do I make use of a generic type for a property in PowerShell 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While crafting my question I stumbled across an [answer which details how to create `Dictionary` objects in PowerShell 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2202519/61654):

```
$object = New-Object 'system.collections.generic.dictionary[string,int]'
```

Of particular note is the lack of the use of `<` and `>` for generic declaration instead using `[` and `]`. Switching my class declaration to use [square brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket#Square_brackets) instead of [angle brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket#Angle_brackets) solved my problem:

```
Class Node
{
    [String]$Label
    [System.Collections.Generic.List[Node]]$Nodes
}
```